# Azure Cosmos DB Client is not a constructor on building and integration into different folder project

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, nuxt.js, package.json

#### Summary

I'm trying to query data from Azure Cosmos DB in my Nuxt 3 application. When I instantiate `ContactMessageCosmosClient`, I received an error saying ContactMessageCosmosClient is not a constructor

#### Root Project

[image: root project]

##### Common Folder

[image: common folder]

`.swcrc` content

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/swcrc",
  "jsc": {
    "parser": {
      "syntax": "typescript"
    }
  },
  "module": {
    "type": "commonjs"
  }
}
```

`.tsconfig` content

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "CommonJS",
    "target": "es6",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "declaration": true,
    "emitDeclarationOnly": true,
    "declarationMap": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "strict": false,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "dist"],
  "include": ["**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx", "**/*.js"]
}
```

`.package.json` content

```
{
  "name": "grominda-common",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "@azure/cosmos": "^3.17.3",
    . . .
  },
  "scripts": {
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "build": "npm run tsc && npx swc ./src --out-dir dist --extensions .ts --copy-files",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@swc/cli": "^0.1.62",
    "@swc/core": "^1.3.56",
    "@types/node": "^20.1.0"
  }
}
```

##### Web Folder

[image: web structure]

`.package.json` content

```
{
  "name": "nuxt-app",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "build-common": "cd ../common && npm run build",
    "build": "npm run build-common && npm install grominda-common && nuxt build",
    "dev": "npm run build-common && npm install grominda-common && nuxt dev",
    "generate": "nuxt generate",
    "preview": "nuxt preview",
    "postinstall": "nuxt prepare"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^18",
    "nuxt": "^3.4.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@pinia/nuxt": "^0.4.9",
    "grominda-common": "file:../common",
    "pinia": "^2.0.35",
    "vuetify": "^3.2.2"
  },
  "overrides": {
    "vue": "latest"
  }
}
```

#### Issue Location

The problem is at the `web/server/api/hello.ts`

`hello.ts` content

```
import ContactMessageCosmosClient from "grominda-common/dist/server/ContactMessageCosmosClient";

export default defineEventHandler(async (event) => {
  const cosmosClient = new ContactMessageCosmosClient();
  const data = await cosmosClient.getAll();

  console.log(cosmosClient);

  return data;
});
```

#### Context

Here are three related files from the `common folder` i.e., `AppCosmosClient.ts`, `BaseCosmosClient.ts`, `ContactMessageCosmosClient.ts`

`AppCosmosClient.ts` content

```
import { CosmosClient } from "@azure/cosmos";

class AppCosmosClient {
  public client: CosmosClient;

  constructor() {
    this.client = new CosmosClient({
      endpoint: "https://example.azure.com:443/",
      key: "example_key",
    });
  }
}

export const appCosmosClient = new AppCosmosClient();
```

`BaseCosmosClient.ts` content

```
import { CosmosClient } from "@azure/cosmos";
import { appCosmosClient } from "./AppCosmosClient";

export default class BaseCosmosClient<TEntity> {
  protected databaseId = "grominda";
  protected containerName: string;

  protected client: CosmosClient;
  protected c: new (initialState?: TEntity) => TEntity;

  constructor(c: new (initialState?: TEntity) => TEntity) {
    this.client = appCosmosClient.client;
    this.c = c;
  }

  public async getById(id: string): Promise<TEntity | null> {
    return this.getByPropertyValue("id", id);
  }

  public async getByPropertyValue(
    propertyName: string,
    value: string
  ): Promise<TEntity | null> {
    const querySpec = {
      query: `SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.${propertyName}=@val`,
      parameters: [{ name: "@val", value: value }],
    };
    const { resources: results } = await this.client
      .database(this.databaseId)
      .container(this.containerName)
      .items.query(querySpec)
      .fetchAll();

    if (results.length > 0) {
      return new this.c(results[0]);
    }

    return null;
  }

  public async getAll(): Promise<TEntity[]> {
    const querySpec = {
      query: `SELECT * FROM c`,
    };
    const { resources: results } = await this.client
      .database(this.databaseId)
      .container(this.containerName)
      .items.query(querySpec)
      .fetchAll();

    return results.map((i) => new this.c(i));
  }
  . . .
}
```

`ContactMessageCosmosClient.ts` content

```
import ContactMessage from "../model/ContactMessage";
import BaseCosmosClient from "./BaseCosmosClient";

export default class ContactMessageCosmosClient extends BaseCosmosClient<ContactMessage> {
  constructor() {
    super(ContactMessage);
    this.containerName = "example_container";
  }

  public async getById(id: string): Promise<ContactMessage | null> {
    return this.getByPropertyValue("id", id);
  }
}
```

The `web` folder is dependent on the `common` folder and it is installed as its dependencies

#### Error

```
[nuxt] [request error] [unhandled] [500] ContactMessageCosmosClient is not a constructor   
  at /C:/Users/Afiq_/Documents/work/grominda/grominda/web/.nuxt/dev/index.mjs:624:24
  at /C:/Users/Afiq_/Documents/work/grominda/grominda/web/node_modules/h3/dist/index.mjs:1191:47      
  at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
  at async Object.handler (/C:/Users/Afiq_/Documents/work/grominda/grominda/web/node_modules/h3/dist/index.mjs:1247:19)
  at async toNodeHandle (/C:/Users/Afiq_/Documents/work/grominda/grominda/web/node_modules/h3/dist/index.mjs:1322:7)
  at async ufetch (/C:/Users/Afiq_/Documents/work/grominda/grominda/web/node_modules/unenv/runtime/fetch/index.mjs:9:17)
  at async $fetchRaw2 (/C:/Users/Afiq_/Documents/work/grominda/grominda/web/node_modules/ofetch/dist/shared/ofetch.502a4799.mjs:180:24)
  at async setup (C:\Users\Afiq_\Documents\work\grominda\grominda\web\app.vue:23:12)
[11:17:34] [nuxt] [request error] [unhandled] [500] ContactMessageCosmosClient is not a constructor   
  at /C:/Users/Afiq_/Documents/work/grominda/grominda/web/.nuxt/dev/index.mjs:624:24
  at /C:/Users/Afiq_/Documents/work/grominda/grominda/web/node_modules/h3/dist/index.mjs:1189:14      
  at Object.handler (/C:/Users/Afiq_/Documents/work/grominda/grominda/web/node_modules/h3/dist/index.mjs:1432:12)
  at Object.handler (/C:/Users/Afiq_/Documents/work/grominda/grominda/web/node_modules/h3/dist/index.mjs:1247:31)
  at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
  at async toNodeHandle (/C:/Users/Afiq_/Documents/work/grominda/grominda/web/node_modules/h3/dist/index.mjs:1322:7)
  at async ufetch (/C:/Users/Afiq_/Documents/work/grominda/grominda/web/node_modules/unenv/runtime/fetch/index.mjs:9:17)
  at async $fetchRaw2 (/C:/Users/Afiq_/Documents/work/grominda/grominda/web/node_modules/ofetch/dist/shared/ofetch.502a4799.mjs:180:24)
  at async setup (C:\Users\Afiq_\Documents\work\grominda\grominda\web\app.vue:23:12)
```

#### Expectation

I'm expecting it to instantiate the CosmosClient and make the query. I'm not sure what went wrong with the setup. Do you know what might cause this issue or how to resolve this problem?